# Android widget layout always squashes ImageButton

Tags: android, layout, widget

I want to create a widget that contains one button to launch certain activity. However, the ImageButton always squashed to size of widget. This is the layout of widget.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appwidget_schedule_button"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/schedule_shortcut" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On the photo: left one is mine. At the right - how it should behave.
[image]

Comment: width and height of RelativeLayout and ImageView are both set to `match_parent` which depends on the screen size. You have to set both to a fixed value like for example `50dp`....

Comment: @opiatefuchs will it cause problems on different screens?

Comment: you mean set a fixed size? You have to be aware of, but it´s too much to explain here. Read the API, that´s the best way to learn: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: All screens have a different size of min dp (cell 1x1 can be rly different on lots of devices), that's why your imageView seems like a broken cuz of match_parent